# QStackedWidget previous index

Tags: qt, qstackedwidget

The signal currentChanged provides the index of the new current widget in a QStackedWidget. Is there a possibility to get the index of the last Widget before the signal currentChanged fired?

Comment: the currentIndex that you have before triggering the signal is the one you want, there is your partial response, but on the other hand you can only know if the signal was triggered, not before. For me you have an XY problem, you could explain why you need that.

Comment: I have to post a REST command if the current widget changed with some informations from the last widget.

Comment: If you post the REST command a moment after the new widget is established, would there be problems?

Comment: Meanwhile i found a solution for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376291/emit-signal-if-all-children-widgets-lose-focus

Works great and i can post the REST command when focusChanged